# SWC-117 signature and ecrecover

Tags: solidity, signature, ecrecover

source code is [here](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-117).

As the SWC-117 says "A signature should never be included into a signed message hash to check if previously messages have been processed by the contract.". I don't know what happened in this contract? How to Hack? What problem is in it?

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
 contract transaction_malleablity{
     mapping(address => uint256) balances;
     mapping(bytes32 => bool) signatureUsed;
     constructor(address[] owners, uint[] init){
         require(owners.length == init.length);
         for(uint i=0; i < owners.length; i ++){
         balances[owners[i]] = init[i];
         }
     }
     function transfer(bytes _signature, address _to, uint256 _value, uint256 _gasPrice, uint256 _nonce) public returns (bool){
         bytes32 txid = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(getTransferHash(_to, _value, _gasPrice, _nonce), _signature));
         require(!signatureUsed[txid]);
         address from = recoverTransferPreSigned(_signature, _to, _value, _gasPrice, _nonce);
         require(balances[from] > _value);
         balances[from] -= _value;
         balances[_to] += _value;
         signatureUsed[txid] = true;
     } // something wrong
     function recoverTransferPreSigned(bytes _sig, address _to, uint256 _value, uint256 _gasPrice, uint256 _nonce) public view returns (address recovered) {
         return ecrecoverFromSig(getSignHash(getTransferHash(_to, _value, _gasPrice, _nonce)), _sig);
     }
     function getTransferHash(address _to, uint256 _value, uint256 _gasPrice, uint256 _nonce) public view returns (bytes32 txHash) {
         return keccak256(address(this), bytes4(0x1296830d), _to, _value, _gasPrice, _nonce);
     }
     function getSignHash(bytes32 _hash) public pure returns (bytes32 signHash){
         return keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash);
     }
     function ecrecoverFromSig(bytes32 hash, bytes sig) public pure returns (address recoveredAddress) {
         bytes32 r;
         bytes32 s;
         uint8 v;
         if (sig.length != 65) return address(0);
         assembly {
             r := mload(add(sig, 32))
             s := mload(add(sig, 64))
             v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
         }
        if (v < 27) {
           v += 27;
         }
         if (v != 27 && v != 28) return address(0);
         return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how someone can exploit it:

1. Alice sends some tokens to Bob using the `transfer` function. All normal so far, since `txid` wasn't seen before then `signatureUsed[txid] == false` and the payment goes through.
2. Bob is our exploiter. He picks the `signature = (r, s, v)` used by Alice and creates a new one `signature2 = (r2, s2, v2)` like this:

```js
r2 = r
s2 = s
v2 = v<27 ? v+27 : v-27
```

3. Bob calls `transfer` with the same parameters used by Alice but using `signature2`. `txid` will be different than before so `signatureUsed[txid] == false`. The signature is also recognized as a valid Alice signature (see how `ecrecoverFromSig` handles `v` ...). So the payment goes through.
4. At then end Bob stole an extra payment from Alice.

The root of the problem is that it's possible to use a signature to make another valid one. This opens up to "replay attacks".

This particular code tries to prevent replay attacks by checking if `txid` was seen before. However `txid` was calculated using the signature, thus failing to prevent this exploit. The fix is just to remove the signature from `txid`.

Comment: Generate a fake signature, is the value like _to, _gasprice, _value, _nonce, still the same as what Alice set?

Comment: Yes, those values are still the same, otherwise the signature won't work.